# Dynamic SOQL Query Exception

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

```
global String taskQuery = 'SELECT Id, Subject, What.Name, CA_Created_by_name__c, Task_Record__c, Task_Dc__c, WhatId, createdDate FROM TASK  WHERE WhatId != NULL AND createdDate >= :Datetime.now().addMinutes(-350) AND (Task_Dc__c = : GlobalConstant.DISEASE_NAME_A OR Task_Dc__c = : GlobalConstant.DISEASE_NAME_B)';
```

the below code is execute method

```
if (runtime == GlobalConstant.A){
    finalTaskQuery = taskQuery + 'AND Task_Record__c IN: userLHJSet AND Subject = :GlobalConstant.TASK_SUBJ_A LIMIT 49999';

    taskListFortypeA = Database.query(finalTaskQuery); 
}
```

taskListFortypeA is defined as List of Tasks and  finalTaskQuery is a string.

it gives an exception as

> System.QueryException:unexpected token: (
> for the line  taskListFortypeA = Database.query(finalTaskQuery);

Comment: You cannot use dot notation for bindings in dynamic SOQL.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic queries can only use simple variable binds. Anything with a dot/period/full-stop in it (e.g. `Datetime.now().addMinutes(-350)`) will not work with a dynamic query. The error appears to be occurring with the open paren for `.now()`.

You could fix this by extracting those complex variable binds and putting them into variables, e.g.

```
DateTime sixHoursAgo = Datetime.now().addMinutes(-360);
String query = 'SELECT Id FROM MyObject__c WHERE CreatedDate > :sixHoursAgo';
```

but honestly, you don't need a dynamic query here. Don't try to be fancy (especially if you don't understand what it is you're doing). Just use a normal, inline SOQL query.

Comment: That's just one issue of many. 

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Apex bind expressions in a dynamic SOQL query:

```
:Datetime.now().addMinutes(-350)
```

Instead, format the date/time value:

```
'... CreatedDate >= ' + DateTime.now().addMinutes(-360).format('YYYY-MM-DD\'T\'KK:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'') +
```

Also, bind expressions don't always work if you include a space between the colon and what comes after:

```
: GlobalConstant.DISEASE_NAME_A
```

And also, you can't use dot-notation (for the same reason why you can't use Apex expressions:

```
: GlobalConstant.DISEASE_NAME_A
```

And you're also missing a space in your dynamic query:

```
finalTaskQuery = taskQuery + 'AND Task_Record__c IN: userLHJSet AND Subject = :GlobalConstant.TASK_SUBJ_A LIMIT 49999';
                           // ^ missing space before AND
```

You'll need to make the query calculate the appropriate values and place them into the string:

```
global String taskQuery = 'SELECT Id, Subject, What.Name, CA_Created_by_name__c, Task_Record__c, Task_Dc__c, '+
  'WhatId, createdDate '+
  'FROM TASK  WHERE WhatId != NULL AND createdDate >= '+ 
  DateTime.now().addMinutes(-360).format('YYYY-MM-DD\'T\'KK:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'') + 
    ' AND (Task_Dc__c = \'' + GlobalConstant.DISEASE_NAME_A + '\' OR Task_Dc__c = \'' + GlobalConstant.DISEASE_NAME_B+'\')';
```

Also, you can use IN for a shorter query:

```
'Task_DC__c IN (\''+GlobalConstant.DISEASE_NAME_A+'\',\'' + GlobalConstant.DISEASE_NAME_B+'\')'
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked.